# Kingdom of Raja and Tempest

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

At time code 1:43:28 of *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime: The Movie – Scarlet Bond* (Cruncyroll), Rimuru toasts, "Here is to the future of the Kingdom of Raja and Tempest".  Nothing else is said about that.  As far as I know, Tempest is not a Kingdom, and even if it were, he toasts to the "Kingdom" not to the "Kingdoms".  Perhaps Raja has been added to the Jura Tempest Federation?

Were the two nations suddenly tied together as one entity, or is that just a typo or poor translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rimuru's line in Japanese is "では、ラージャ小亜国とテンペストの未来をしゅくして！" (Dewa, Ra-ja shoakoku to Tempesuto no mirai wo shuku shite) and that makes it pretty clear that it's meant to be processed as "[The Kingdom of Raja] and [Tempest]", *not* "The Kingdom of [Raja and Tempest]".

So no, there hasn't been any kind of merger or promotion of the nations involved, he's just wishing the two nations to have a good future working together, and on that basis the sentence works perfectly fine.